# Print specific content

Tags: posts

I want to print specific content ( table ) in my page
http://ahanalat.co/%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af/%d9%85%db%8c%d9%84%da%af%d8%b1%d8%af-%d8%a2%d8%ac%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b1/%d9%82%d8%b2%d9%88%db%8c%d9%86/

I just want to print the table in this page

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcode that will print table into your page or page content. You can call shortcode using this syntax. e.g. [your-shortcode-name]

see this link.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

You can pass arguments and parameters also.

```
add_shortcode('shortcode-name','my_shortcode_handler'); 

function my_shortcode_handler($arg) {
    return "<some table tags>";
}
```

Comment: I want the function

Comment: You have to create a shortcode handler and call that shortcode into your content. e.g. add_shortcode('shortcode-name','my_shortcode_handler');

function my_shortcode_handler($arg) {
    return "<some table tags>";
}